# Queries to create custom Profit and Loss Report in SAP B1

Tags: sql, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to create a custom profit and loss statement using crystal reports. I am using a previous set of sql scripts in order to modify them to suit my needs.
I am using 2 views, a function and a stored procedure to achieve this. (code is a bit long)

**vw_Transactions**

```
USE [EUROPA_PROD_DB]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[vw_Transactions]    Script Date: 05/04/2012 12:51:24 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Transactions] AS
SELECT 
TA.AcctCode,TA.AcctName,TA.GroupMask,TA.Levels,TA.ActType,TA.L1Parent,TA.L2Parent,
TA.L3Parent,TA.L4Parent,
TH.TransId,TH.TransType,TH.RefDate PostingDate,TH.DueDate,
TH.TaxDate,TD.Account,TD.Debit,TD.Credit
FROM OJDT TH
INNER JOIN JDT1 TD ON TH.TransId=TD.TransId
INNER JOIN vw_AccountDetails TA ON TD.Account=TA.AcctCode

GO
```

Sample results from above view

[image]

**vw_AccountDetails** - this view enables me to get the various levels (ie parents) as can be seen in the image above. The column GroupMask refers to the following below:

```
1 - assets
2 - liabilities
4 - turnover
5 - Cost of sales
6 - operating costs.
```

**fn_CustomProfit_And_Loss** - function

```
ALTER FUNCTION fn_CustomProfit_And_Loss
(
    @BeginDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS @table TABLE(
    L1Parent VARCHAR(72),
    L2Parent VARCHAR(72),
    Balance MONEY,
    RowOrder INT
)
AS
BEGIN
SET @BeginDate=CAST(YEAR(@BeginDate) AS CHAR(4))+'-'+CAST(MONTH(@BeginDate) AS CHAR(2)) +'-'+ CAST(DAY(@BeginDate) AS CHAR(2))
SET @EndDate=CAST(YEAR(@EndDate) AS CHAR(4))+'-'+CAST(MONTH(@EndDate) AS CHAR(2)) +'-'+ CAST(DAY(@EndDate) AS CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT 
CASE L1Parent WHEN 'Turnover' THEN 'Income' ELSE L1Parent END L1Parent,
L2Parent,
SUM(Credit-Debit) Balance,
1 RowOrder
FROM vw_Transactions
WHERE GroupMask=4--Income
AND PostingDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY L1Parent,L2Parent

UNION ALL
SELECT 
CASE L1Parent WHEN 'Cost of Sales' THEN 'Cost Of Goods Sold' ELSE L1Parent END L1Parent,
L2Parent,
SUM(Debit-Credit) Balance,
2 RowOrder
FROM vw_Transactions
WHERE GroupMask=5--COGS
AND PostingDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY L1Parent,L2Parent

UNION ALL

SELECT 
CASE L1Parent WHEN 'Operating Costs' THEN 'Expenses' ELSE L1Parent END L1Parent,
L2Parent,
SUM(Debit-Credit) Balance,
3 RowOrder
FROM vw_Transactions
WHERE GroupMask IN(6)--Expenses
AND PostingDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY L1Parent,L2Parent

RETURN
END
```

**sp_CustomProfit_And_Loss** - stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_CustomProfit_And_Loss
(
    @BeginDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT L1Parent,L2Parent,Balance,RowOrder
    FROM fn_CustomProfit_And_Loss(@BeginDate,@EndDate)
    order by RowOrder

END
```

What I basically need is to to have a P & L statement that is grouped per department. i.e

```
                          BRANDING1       BRANDING2      PROMOS 

 Sales-Gross Revenue    18237            121143          91092

 COST OF SALES          
 Direct Purchases          
 Labour                    
 KEBS Levy              
 Marketing               
 Packaging Materials     
 Clearing                    
 Car hire and transport     
 Licence Local Authority 
 Courier freight & postage  
 Travel and Accomodation    
     -       -
```

How can I modify my SQL statements in order to have a P & L statement that groups per department? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a very lenghty and confusing too.

I will try to provide the solution to the extent I understand.

1. You have 2 views and some procedure that populate these views so in a CR link those views.
2. If columns are readily available then group as per the Gross revenue and place columns as Branding one...etc and take sum of those with options readily available in CR

Above solution works if you views in the report.

If your requirement is something different then let me know will try to help